# swagger/flask: how to handle query parameters with dashes

Tags: python-3.x, flask, yaml, swagger, openapi

I have generated a flask server with Swagger/OpenAPI, using an YAML definition file. An extract of a GET endpoint:

```
 parameters:
    - in: query
      name: project-name
      required: true
      schema:
        type: string
      description: name of the project
    - in: query
      name: file-name
      required: true
      schema:
        type: string
      description: name of the origin file of the dataset
    - in: query
      name: null-management
      required: true
      schema:
        type: string
      description: value to use to fill null values in datasets
    - in: query
      name: category-name
      schema:
        type: string
      description: name of the first level category
    - in: query
      name: filter-multi-occurrence
      schema:
        type: boolean
        description: if multi occurrences are to be filtered or not
```

the problem is that I cannot map it with Python/Flask controller, because the variables should be like this

```
def dataset_add(project_name: str, file_name: str, null_management: str, first_level_category_name: str = None,
            filter_multi_occurrence: str = None) -> str:  # noqa: E501
```

... and dashes are not allowed in Python's variable names. But I don't wanna use underscores in GET query... how can I solve this problem in Flask?

Answer (score 3):

You can actually do that but using a workaround.

First you need to update the `swagger/swagger.yaml` in the generated code and make sure all the param names have `-` instead of `_`

Then you need to update your function and remove the `_` from the parameter name

```py
def dataset_add(projectname: str, filename: str, nullmanagement: str, firstlevelcategoryname: str = None,
            filtermultioccurrence: str = None) -> str:  # noqa: E501
```

[image: Working fine]

Comment: That is the way generator works, so it has nothing to do with `connexion`